# How to iterate through a HashSet and return the set with qualified elements?

Tags: java, loops, hash, iterator, hashset

What I am trying to do is reading from a text file that contains 500,000 English words and store it to a HashSet for the performance purpose. And then I want to return a HashSet that contains qualified elements, for example, 5-letter words, 6-letter words, etc.

This is my code so far, I don't know how to make it do.
I appreciate your solution!

```
 private static HashSet<String> readPuzzleFile(int wordLength) {
        HashSet<String> unProcessedPuzzle = new HashSet<String>();
        try (Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(PATHTOPUZZLE))) {
            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                unProcessedPuzzle.add(file.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No Puzzle File Found!");
            return null;
        }
        HashSet<String> puzzle = new HashSet<String>();
        Iterator iterator = unProcessedPuzzle.iterator();
        for (String word : unProcessedPuzzle){
            puzzle.addAll(word);
        }
       }
```

Comment: And what is your problem or your question?

Comment: @IQV Just how to do it, sorry forgot to put it in the question the first time.

Comment: How to do what?

Comment: This sounds like a textbook case for streams or Groovy iterator methods.

Comment: @TianchengXu if you have solved this as your comment below suggests then please close the question or post and accept your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private static HashSet<String> readPuzzleFile(int wordLength) {
        HashSet<String> unProcessedPuzzle = new HashSet<String>();
        try (Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(PATHTOPUZZLE))) {
            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                unProcessedPuzzle.add(file.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No Puzzle File Found!");
            return null;
        }
        HashSet<String> puzzle = new HashSet<String>();
        Iterator iterator = unProcessedPuzzle.iterator();
        for (String word : unProcessedPuzzle){
            puzzle.add(word); //........addAll -> add.........
        }
        return puzzle;//........return puzzle.........
       }
```

Comment: Although this is not the correct way, but you inspired me. Now I solved it, thank you!